# Criteria to consider when evaluating interest point detectors

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, object-recognition

I want to evaluate different interest point detectors like FAST, MSER, DOH and DOG for images of certain kinds of objects.

As a first criterion I came up with repeatability under certain conditions like lighting or scale. I think it is also interesting to see which kind of region around a point favors a selection as interest point.

What are some more criteria to consider for that kind of evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at these two papers to get a good sense of thorough evaluation:

- [A performance evaluation of local descriptors](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00548529/en)
- [A comparison of affine region detectors](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00548528/en)

Comment: Thanks, those are indeed two good papers. I'll go through them and see what they propose ;-)